# Discharge of a capacitor with variable backvoltage?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, capacitance

I understand that the voltage of a capacitor as it discharges overtime is $$V(t)=V_0e^(-t/RC).$$
I've also heard people say things like "voltage is relative. The voltage to the ground or the voltage to this other part of the circuit are different things". Well, the above equation has the voltage exponentially decaying to zero. So I figured If I have a capacitor charged to 10 volts, and I connect it to an 8 volt power supply, the capacitor's charge will exponentially decay to 8 volts. Seems reasonable. so $$V(t)=(V_0-V_b)((e^t/RC)+1)$$ is an equation I made up that exponentially decays to $V_b$. I guess my first question is "is that equation correct (when V_b is constant)?"

I assume for now it is. I want to know, what if `V_b` is itself a function of time? Then for sure the above equation is incorrect. (what if for the first second `V_b` was 0, then at `t=1` `V_b=8`; if we plugged in `t=1` and `v_b=8` into the above , we'd get that the decay was the same as if it had been `v_b=8`  the entire time, which is obviously incorrect.)

So how does `V(t)` evolve with time if `V_b` is allowed to vary? I've tried to figure this out on my own, with no success. Here's what I've figured.

`V(t+1)=(V(t)-V_b(t))*e^(Δt/RC) +V(t)-V_b(t)` (If it isn't obvious how this equation follows from the above, consider if we just kept resetting `V_0` to `V(t)`. After all, `t=0` is an arbitrary assignment)

`V(t+1)-V(t) = (V(t)-V_b(t))*e^(Δt/RC) - V_b(t)`

`ΔV/Δt = ( (V(t)-V_b(t))*e^(Δt/RC) - V_b(t) )/Δt`

Now if we allow Δt to approach zero... I'm stuck. I feel like I'm really close to getting an ODE , but not quite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $V(t)=(V_0-V_b)(e^{t/RC}+1)$ is an equation I made up that exponentially decays to $V_b$. I guess my first question is "is that equation correct (when $V_b$ is constant)?"

Your verbal description is right, but isn't translated into the correct equation, which is
$$V(t) = V_b + (V_0 - V_b)e^{-t/(RC)}.$$
Check that it has the correct values at $t = 0$ and $t \to \infty$.

We can use this equation to derive the general equation for time-varying $V_b$. Starting at $t$ and evaluating the capacitor voltage at a very short time $\Delta t$ later, we can write

$$V(t + \Delta t) \approx V_b(t) + [V(t) - V_b(t)]e^{-\Delta t/(RC)}.$$
For small $\Delta t$, in the first order Taylor expansion we have $e^{-\Delta t/(RC)} \approx 1 - \frac{\Delta t}{RC}$. Using this and rearranging, we get
$$ RC\frac{V(t + \Delta t)-V(t)}{\Delta t}\approx V_b(t) - V(t).$$
In the limit $\Delta t \to 0$, this becomes
$$ RC\frac{dV}{dt} + V = V_b .$$
This is the differential equation you are looking for.

---

The more systematic, orthodox approach is to use [Kirchhoff's two circuit laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws) to get the differential equation. Let $I$ be the current flowing out of the out of the positive terminal of the battery and into the positive terminal of the capacitor. If $Q$ is the charge on the positive terminal of the capacitor,
$$Q = CV$$
$$I = \frac{dQ}{dt} = C\frac{dV}{dt}.$$
This is the terminal relation of an ideal capacitor.

Kirchhoff's voltage law around the loop can be written as

$$V = V_b - RI,$$
i.e. the capacitor voltage is the battery voltage, less the voltage drop in the series resistance. Substituting $I$ from above,
$$RC \frac{dV}{dt} + V = V_b.$$

Comment: Thank you. I see part of my problem is I made an equation that decays to the difference between the voltages, rather than the lower voltage.